# É possível auxiliar na tradução do site?

Tags: suporte, tradução, edição, beta

Gostaria de saber se é possível contribuir com a tradução do Stackoverflow para o português, e caso sim, o que a pessoa deve fazer para se candidatar como tradutor?

Comment: Olá, eu havia lido esta *thread* mas ela não responde efetivamente o que está sendo perguntado aqui. Obrigado mesmo assim!

Comment: Existe essa outra também http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/4/como-reportar-erros-na-traducao. E tem mais alguma em outro lugar. O fato é que já foi tratado que não podemos traduzir o site. Isso será feito pela equipe do SE e nós vamos apenas reportar bugs nas traduções.

Comment: Obrigado, isso não estava claro até o momento. Seria legal se uma resposta fosse adicionada aqui para deixar absurdamente claro que não é possível contribuir com as traduções.

Comment: Sou a favor de fechar como duplicata das outras duas. @karlphillip A resposta do Gabe no segundo link do bigown me parece bem clara. Se é "absurdamente" clara eu já não sei! :)

Comment: Só para registrar, legal que você tem interesse em colaborar com a tradução. Infelizmente não existe ferramenta para isso (acho que foi uma decisão *muito errada* da Stack Exchange, mas enfim...), então o único jeito de colaborar é postando suas colaborações caso a caso aqui no meta.